# (Swift3) Can return the full JSON file but I cannot return a specific value, what am I doing incorrectly?

Tags: ios, json, swift3, swifty-json

I have a local JSON file named as such: testTheJSON.json

```
{"myJSON":
[{
 "ID1" :
    {"name":"Stack",
    "LastName": "Overflow"
    },
 "ID2" :
    {"name":"Cat",
    "last":"dog",
    }
 }
 ]
}
```

and I try to read in the file as such:

```
func parseJSON() {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testTheJSON", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)! as NSData!
    let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil)
    var name = readableJSON["myJSON","ID1","name"]
    print(readableJSON) //returns the full JSON script
    print (name) //returns null
}
```

Why does `print(readableJSON)` return the full JSON file and `print(name)` return as null? Am I doing the `var name = readableJSON["myJSON","ID1","name"]` line incorrectly? Thanks!

EDIT: I am using the SwiftyJSON framework - this is where the JSON method is from. I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NfijT6mt6A

Comment: What is `JSON`? There's no such class in iOS.

Comment: Added an edit above, this is from the SwiftyJSON framework .

Comment: You should completely remove use of NSData from that code. The Swift 3 type you want to use is Data throughout.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. If you downvoted, please provide a reason why so I can incorporate your feedback in my future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *correctly* reading in the contents of your *testTheJSON.json* file and asking SwiftyJSON to parse it. (Your code makes some rather poor use of the NSData class, but that's not actually causing anything to go wrong.)

The problem is that your *testTheJSON.json* file is *not valid JSON.* Therefore the parse fails and `nil` is returned — which is actually correct behavior. Therefore, nothing is wrong. We *want* the parser to fail when it is handed invalid data.

That actually answers the question, but as a bonus, I will also give you a *valid* version of your file:

```
{"myJSON":
[{
 "ID1" :
    {"name":"Stack",
    "LastName": "Overflow"
    },
 "ID2" :
    {"name":"Cat",
    "last":"dog"
    }
 }
 ]
}
```

Do you see the difference? (Hint: it's after `"dog"`.)

After that, you can fix your subscripted expression, which is currently wrong. It should be:

```
let name = readableJSON["myJSON"][0]["ID1"]["name"]
```

Or you can write it as:

```
let name = readableJSON["myJSON",0,"ID1","name"]
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried using this JSON file you provided but the same behavior from my question is exhibited. Is there a better way I can try to make the same call?

Comment: "but the same behavior from my question is exhibited" No, it isn't! You are wrong. `name` is still null, but `readableJSON` is now showing the parsed file correctly. — Added code to replace your nonsensical derivation of `name` so now it won't be null either.